# I keep receiving this error message: del: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, unix

I keep receiving this error message: 
`del: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

This is my script:

```
  1 echo -e "Enter a filename"
  2 read filename
  3 if [$filename = myfirst]
  4 then
  5   echo -e "do you want to delete?"
  6 read answer
  7 if [answer= Y]
  8 then rm myfirst
  9 else [answer = N]
 10 echo -e "file not deleted"
 11 fi
 12 exit0
```

Comment: Count `if` and `fi`. They don't match.

Comment: when I use the bash command ex: bash del. I receive a syntax error: expected end of file.

Comment: can you explain futher?

Answer (score 1):

Your **if/fi** syntax is not complete or closed (missing **fi**).

To detect such bugs prior to running your script you should always use

```
 bash -n scriptname
```

This performs a syntax check detecting such problems without actually running the script.